# String not passing through segue?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to build a cell that can be tapped, store the current text of the cell label, and send that label to a different view controller. I've looked everywhere and can't figure out why it's not passing

View controller with table view

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "openWave" {
        if let destVC = segue.destination as? GoToWaveViewController {
            destVC.waveLabel = sender as! String
            print("sdf: \(sender)")
        }
    }
} ...

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! MyWavesTableViewCell
    let text = cell.waveLabel.text!
    let label = self.groupNames[indexPath.row]
    print(label)
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "openWave", sender: label)
    //self.tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)}
```

Second View Controller

```
class GoToWaveViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var waveName: UILabel!
var waveLabel: String!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    setProperties()
}

func setProperties() {
    self.waveLabel = self.waveName.text!
    print("asdf: \(waveLabel)")
    print("asdfa: \(self.waveLabel)")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see it's a logical error you may need

```
self.waveName.text =  self.waveLabel
```

Instead of

```
self.waveLabel = self.waveName.text!
```

And that overwrites the sended value , so this

```
print("asdf: \(waveLabel)")
print("asdfa: \(self.waveLabel)")
```

will print empty values

Comment: Loll can't believe I overlooked that. Thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

Well, when your view appears, you call `setProperties`, which *overwrites* `self.waveLabel` with the text from `self.waveName`. This line

```
self.waveLabel = self.waveName.text!
```

should be replaced with

```
self.waveName.text = self.waveLabel
```

Secondarily, fix your names! `Label` is a bad name for something that is a `string`.  If I were looking at this code, it's immediately think that `waveName` is a string and `waveLabel` is the label, but that is the opposite of what you have here.